# Setting to change IE behavior of remembering the passwords when opening the same url in different window

Tags: internet-explorer, passwords

I have windows XP with SP3 on my system. My current IE version is 8.
Now for some product testing, I want to log-in 100 users to a website one after other. My problem is IE8 remembers the passwords, so when I log-in to the website and open the same url in some other window, I am already signed in with the previous username and password. What setting do I need to change so that this doesn't happens? Or is there any other web browser that doesn't behave like this? I tried Google Chrome, Opera and Mozilla Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one account at time, just try logout before you try another account.

But if you need simultaneously more accounts, you should each account open in different browser.

Comment: I want to log-in 100 users one after another and keep them logged in. 
And I am automating this thing, so I cant use another browser. I have to use same browser and different window

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser with private browsing. Most often, sites "remember" your login through cookies, not passwords (unless you're talking about plain HTTP authentication, in which case the browser does remember the password for each connection). Either way, I would recommend Google Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+N for new "private" window). This will not have the passwords or cookies from any previous windows.